# SetInterval/SetTimeout with Countdown Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to have a function set to run at an interval

```
setInterval(function, 360000);
```

When it's called, it will load some info from Ajax/Flask, but won't refresh or reload the page.

How can I display a countdown in a div that shows time remaining until the function/interval is next triggered?

Comment: For best possible answer include all relevant code.

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the count of the interval? And the page won't reload hence the use of ajax...

Comment: Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried to solve inquiry at Question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a very long timer (six minutes in the code you listed), use a much shorter timer, e.g. a one second timer. Update your div each time that timer fires, and keep track of how many times it gets called. For example:

```
var secondsBetweenActions = 360;
var secondsRemaining = secondsBetweenActions;
setInterval( function() {
    updateStatus( secondsRemaining );
    secondsRemaining--;
    if( secondsRemaining <= 0 ) {
        doAction();
        secondsRemaining = secondsBetweenActions;
    }
}, 1000 );
```

Now you just need to implement `updateStatus()` which should display `secondsRemaining` in your status `div` using jQuery, and `doAction()` which does whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Michael, great solution.

Comment: My pleasure, Atol, glad that was helpful. Happy hacking!